# What is the convention for searching for JPA Entities that have a Foreign Key?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, relational-database

I am developing a Movie Theater API to provide the back end functionality that a movie ticket reservation service would require (Reserve seats for a specific screening of a certain movie, etc.).

I have a seat entity defined below:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Seat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    private String seatRow;

    private Integer seatNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    private Auditorium auditorium;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "seat")
    private Set<Reservation> reservation;

}
```

I want to be able to search for seats in the database by id, seatRow, seatNumber, and auditorium. I would like to know if there is a convention for searching through JPA entities that have a foreign key (in my case Auditorium). Should I be searching for Seat by comparing id, seatRow, seatNumber, and Auditorium like example 1, or id, seatRow, seatNumber, and auditoriumId like example 2?

Example 1:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Seat s WHERE (:id is null or s.id = :id) and " +
        "(:seatRow is null or s.seatRow = :seatRow) and " +
        "(:seatNumber is null or s.seatNumber = :seatNumber) and" +
        "(:auditorium is null or s.auditorium = :auditorium)")
ArrayList<Seat> searchSeats(Integer id, String seatRow, Integer seatNumber, Auditorium auditorium);
```

Example 2:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Seat s WHERE (:id is null or s.id = :id) and " +
        "(:seatRow is null or s.seatRow = :seatRow) and " +
        "(:seatNumber is null or s.seatNumber = :seatNumber) and" +
        "(:auditorium is null or s.auditorium.id = :auditoriumId)")
ArrayList<Seat> searchSeats(Integer id, String seatRow, Integer seatNumber, Integer auditoriumId);
```

My GET mapping for a search would be using the auditoriumId as a parameters since I think that is easiest for the user, but I'm not sure if my repository queries should attempt to best match the structure of the Entity I am searching for.

Comment: Do both approaches work as expected?

Comment: @Turing85 I have attempted both and both work, but using the Auditorium search requires that I grab the Auditorium entity from the repository before searching with it, whereas the auditoriumId approach more closely matches the GET search request and does not require fetching entities prior to the search query. I'm just unsure if there's a pre-existing design pattern I should be trying to stick with since this is my first Spring Boot project.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest to use the latter approach (filtering on `s.auditorium.id`). What we should check, however, is if whether this query will generate a `JOIN` on the `Seat`-table.

Comment: If the above query generates a join and this is unwanted, itt would be to "*double-map*" the foreign key, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476273/hibernate-select-id-of-join-column-without-join/52479548) for details.

Comment: The `auditorium, seatRow, seatNumber` identifies the seat. Why do you need an `id` as well? Why are any of these nullable? Don't put a row into the table until you have a reservation. That'll make your search logic easier.